# Finding the volume of a helical structure generated by the rotation of a square about an axis

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A fixed line $L$ in 3-space and a square of side $r$ in a plane perpendicular to $L$ are given. One vertex of the square is on $L$. As this vertex moves a distance $h$ along $L$, the square turns through a full revolution with $L$ as the axis. Find the volume of the solid generated by this motion.

I was solving problems from the book **A Course in Calculus and Real Analysis** and encountered this problem on page 353 (http://books.google.co.in/books?id=F8zgg3I_xsQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Physically I can understand a helical structure will be generated, but I have not been able to think of any method to calculate the volume, either by Shell or Washer method. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as described on pages 298-299, section *Slicing by Planes Perpendicular to a Fixed Line*, particularly equation:

$$\mbox{Vol}(D) = \int_a^b{A(x)\,dx}.$$

where $A(x)$ is the area of the "slice" of the given solid at position $x$ on the $x$-axis.

In your case, the slice is always the square, so $A(x) = r^2, \forall\, x$. Since $A(x)$ is a constant, the integral simplifies to a multiplication:

$$\mbox{Vol}(D) = (b-a)r^2 = hr^2.$$

Note that it doesn't matter by how much the square is rotating, or whether it is rotating at all: the slice area is the same so the volume of the solid is the same. This is basically what [Cavalieri's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle) says.